# git on new machine and connecting to existing github account

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-14.04

I have a github account and had created some repositories an year back. Yesterday, my Ubuntu OS(14.04) was reinstalled by formatting my machine.I want to install git and connect to my existing github account.

As I understood, I have to do this

```
sudo apt-get install git
git config --global user.name="damon"
git config --global user.email="damon@somemail.com"
```

After this, do I have to generate a new SSH key and add it to ssh-agent, and add this SSH key to my github account? The page at https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ suggests this.

Or is there something else I missed?

Comment: Well yeah in principle that's it. You gotta generate the keys and upload them to the site. Doesn't it work?

Comment: That's it. Then to download your code do `git clone <some github link>`. Check that the github link you copy from your project's github page is the ssh link. The https link works as well but with https you need to enter your password every time you push.